# Take a result set (eg. listofcomputers.txt) and run a copy-item command on every item of result set

Tags: variables, powershell, pipe, token, copy-item

Hi all: This is what I'm trying to do....
Take a result set **(eg. listoffailedcomputers.txt)** and run a copy command on every item inside the result set.
The logic is to run a copy command on all the computers in that **failedlistofcomputers.txt** so that the end result will have that folder copied down locally on all computers on that list.
I can do this by using a remote console on all those computers but that would not be efficient.
Thank You.

Here is the code that I wrote so far.......

```
$failedcomputers = gc c:\listoffailedcomputers.txt
foreach ($failedcomputer in $failedcomputers)
{
$failedcomputer | copy-item \\server\patch\*.* -destination c:\patch\
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting......

```
Copy-Item : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command 
either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its
properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At copypatchtofailedcomputers.ps
+ $failedcomputer | copy-item <<<<  \\server\patch\ -destination c:\patch\
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (mycomputername:PSObject) [Copy- 
   Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Command 
   s.CopyItemCommand
```

If I remove the pipe between the $failedcomputer variable and the copy-item command on my statement, I'll get a unexpected token error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility:

```
$failedcomputers = gc c:\listoffailedcomputers.txt

$CmdParams = 
@{ 
   ClassName  = 'Win32_Process'
   MethodName = 'Create'
   Arguments  = @{ CommandLine = 'copy \\server\patch\*.* c:\patch\' }
 }


Invoke-CimMethod @CmdParams -ComputerName $failedcomputers
```

That should multi-thread it, without the overhead of spinning up a bunch of remote PS instances just to do a file copy.

Answer (score 5):

You can't just pipe a computername into any cmdlet and expect it to understand how to use it. `Copy-Item` doesn't even include a `-ComputerName` parameter. You could try two approaches

You could remote execute `copy-item` on each computer, like this:

```
$failedcomputers = gc c:\listoffailedcomputers.txt
foreach ($failedcomputer in $failedcomputers)
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $failedcomputer -ScriptBlock { copy-item \\server\patch\*.* -destination c:\patch\ }
}
```

Or, if you have file access to all remote computers from your computer, you could try to copy directly from one network share to another(the destination computer), like this:

```
$failedcomputers = gc c:\listoffailedcomputers.txt
foreach ($failedcomputer in $failedcomputers)
{
    copy-item \\server\patch\*.* -destination "\\$failedcomputer\c$\patch\"
}
```

Comment: If you consider this the correct answer, please use the checkmark under the votes to confirm it. The same goes for your earlier question. :)

Comment: Excellent answers from both of you. Graimer helped me realize that even though powershell looks plain-english to me more than anything, you can't expect cmdlets to dynamically understand a parameter that does not belong to it. Successful parsing requires that every step has direct understanding of all other adjacent steps. Mjolinor helped me understand a sufficient option that worked. I did not have to resort to using bits or robocopy to throttle speed and check integrity; even though they seem to play quite well with ps.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `Get-Help Copy-Item -full` in ISE it tells you what it can accept on the pipeline. You can pipe a string that contains a path to Copy-ItemProperty. You are actually piping a hostname in this instance, which is why you are getting that error.

Try this:

```
    copy-item \\server\patch\*.* -destination \\$failedcomputer\C$\patch
```

Comment: Gotcha! making more sense to me now. Thank You.